# Post animation link switch

Tags: jquery, animation, html

I have an animation set to slide a DIV down when the DOWN link is clicked. I'd like to have the down link replaced by an UP link when the animation is ended so that the DIV can be returned. The JQuery to animate the DIV back to its starting position is set. The only thing I am having difficulty with is switching between the Down and Up DIVs.

Here's the code http://jsfiddle.net/pC6fC/20/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could specify the callback to be run once the animation is complete, like so:

```
var toggleButton = function () {
    $(".link, .link1").toggle();
};

/* Slides down alert banner */
$(function(){ 
    $(".link").click(function(){
        $(".box1").animate({'margin-top':150}, 500, toggleButton);
    });
});

/* Slides up alert banner */
$(function(){
    $(".link1").click(function(){
        $(".box1").animate({'margin-top':0}, 500, toggleButton);
    });
});
```

I also changed `visibility: hidden` to `display: none` on your CSS.

See the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZcQVV/).

Comment: This worked well in terms of just having two DIVS set inside the HTML and a simple toggle. Like it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ttu9t/

```
<div class="link">DOWN</div>
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>​
```

js:

```
$(function(){ 
     $(document).on('click', '.link', function(){
        $('.box1').animate({'margin-top':150}, 500);
        $(this).text('UP');
        $(this).removeClass('link');
        $(this).addClass('link1');
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.link1', function(){
        $('.box1').animate({'margin-top':0}, 500);
        $(this).text('DOWN');
        $(this).removeClass('link1');
        $(this).addClass('link');
    });
});
```

​and don't forget to make link1 visible:

```
.link1 {
}
```

---

UPDATE

http://jsfiddle.net/ttu9t/2/

Comment: I think this could be improved by using a callback. Since the animation happens asynchronously, the button changes before the animation has completed. jQuery's [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) takes a callback function as the last argument which will be run once the animation is complete.

Comment: yes, absolutely. i don't know your exact requirements so the above code is just a suggestion. there are few other ways to do what you require. it's up to you to decide. see my updated fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to use the function toggle() to do this.

It is used to hide or display a div.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function togglefield(classname) {
      $("." + classname).toggle("slow")
 </script>



 <button onclick="togglefield('test')"> test </button>

 <div class="info"><br/><br/><br/></div>
```

This may certainly be improved, but that's what I've thought about your needs.